# How to change media folder from created time of the post to publish date?

Tags: uploads, media-library

Now, all the structure of the media folder is under /wp-content/uploads/ and years-months combination from the created date of the post.
Is it possible that his path will automatically change to /wp-content/uploads/ and the publish date of the post (Of course , if it was set before!!)?

E.G. Today is 2nd of December of 2023, so any media I create on my post is created under /wp-content/uploads/2023/12 structure. But if I set before that publish date is the 3rd of September of 2021 I want that media will be created under /wp-content/uploads/2021/09.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not try it and see where the file goes?

Comment: Hi @Caleb I tried it and it only worked if:
1 - I create a new article
2 - Change publish data and safe it as a draft.
3 - Add a classic block from guttember style and inside it, add media.

I was asking if its possible to do it on the code, maybe modifying _wp_handle_upload function?

Thanks!